# Can log into chat, but can't use a specific room

Tags: support, chat

I can log into the chat rooms, but am unable to chat in the Python room. The text area is disabled.  What's the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need 20 reputation to chat.  You currently have 1 rep:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1860261/alex-kasina

Additionally, your account is suspended, so you can't chat.

Comment: To be fair, he wasn't suspended at the time of writing this, and had 300 and some reputation.